# Como replicar datos de una base de datos a otra mediante una api?

Tags: postgresql, api

Muy buenos días tengo una base de datos Postgres en un servidor A en la cual se insertan datos de vehículos constantemente, mi necesidad es replicar esos datos insertados en esta base de datos en otra base de datos que estará alojada en otro servidor, esta tabla en la nueva base de datos tiene una estructura mas acortada ya que no es necesario pasar todos los datos. Mi pregunta es como poder hacer para que estos datos sean replicados mediante una api? soy nuevo en esto y la verdad no se por donde empezar.

```
Tabla base de datos 1 
trama_gps
--lat
--long
--estado
--device
-orientacion
....(los demas campos)
```

```
Tabla base de datos 2 
Posición
--lat
--long
-orientación
```

Comment: Porque mediante una api y no simplemente con una conexion entre las bases y un trigger? como seria tu api? quien la llamaria?

Comment: Pues si esa era mi idea principal, pero es que el requerimiento que me hicieron es que no siempre va obtener los datos desde esta base de datos A, si no que también puede obtenerlas desde otra Api, no entiendo mucho del BackEnd pues la primera vez que trabajo con esto y lo que me solicitaron es que debe estar siempre en escucha esta api, por eso no se como hacer no se si la api sea la mejor solución o exista otra manera.

Comment: Creo que lo que te pidieron es muy vago como para poder darte una respuesta. Desconozco si podes programar una api en postgersql, pero de no ser asi, deberia estar en algun lenguaje. Creo que mas que una pregunta para aca, es una pregunta para el arquitecto del sistema que estas desarrollando...

Comment: Osea quieres replicar los mismos datos desde otras bases de datos y otras apis?? Osea múltiples formas?? Si bien tu pregunta es interesante es muy amplia y basada en opiniones... Claro podemos ayudarte, pero sé más concreto porque hasta donde dice tu pregunta... "cómo poder hacer..."